# How to make magento 2.2.1 website search results more accurate

Tags: search, magento-2.2.1

How to make Magento 2.2.1 website search results more accurate?

Now I have developed a new site, it uses the Magento 2.2.1 version, I contact the Magento 2.2.1 version the first time. And I have to search it via google, but couldn't found the result.

So I need to find the help from here? I'm forward to your help, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have done this before which is improved search results. Try this -

**Step 1 :** Go to admin -> Stores -> Click on "Product" (Under Attributes).

**Step 2 :** Filter searchable attributes from Grid.
[image: Like this -]

**Step 3 :** Make searchable "No" which product attribute value key you don't want to see in search. Like - Description .

**Step 4 :** Re-index and clear cache from admin.

That's All.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main routes you can take to improve the Magento search results:

1. re-configure the built-in Magento search engine ([please check this blog](https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/magento-2-how-to-configure-catalog-search/)) OR
2. use an external SaaS solution to power your search results.

I personally can recommend taking the 2nd option for better results both in terms of the latency and ease of use.  I can recommend our very own InstantSearch+ for Magento Extension (https://www.instantsearchplus.com/instantsearchplus-autocomplete-magento) but there are other options as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use ElastcSuite which is quite relevant out of the box and very tunable : https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite
It's free and open source.