# Magento 2 Search, result of search should must be searched product first than relevant product

Tags: magento2.3, search, catalogsearch

I want the search result to be more accurate when I search a product actual product is result   on 3rd page

I want searched product result first then all remaining relevant products

example when i search a product  MOIRÉ DOUBLE CASE - than the result get all product name that contains MOIRÉ, DOUBLE, CASE words I need product search to start with LIKE %MOIRÉ DOUBLE CASE

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/207652/how-to-make-magento-2-2-1-website-search-results-more-accurate

Comment: @Pramod Thank for rply but thats not working in my case I need exactly same when we search product

Comment: check my updated ans

Comment: @Pramod I tried your code but when I search a product result get empty
 Your search returned no results.

Comment: did you run the di:compile after removing generated also you may check the logs for debugging purpose and please sahre the error if possible

Comment: @Pramod Yes it is work but products name like **XL MOIRÉ DOUBLE HANDLE TRAVEL CASE**,  **XL SPF 50+ Wet Skin Gel Sunscreen**, **XL SPF 50+ Nutritive Comfort Sunscreen Oil** etc..
not working when I search above product names is there something issue with **XL**

Comment: this is just a basic idea on how to achieve this rest you can customize it according to your conditions once you have understanding

Comment: @Pramod ok thanks, i guess 2 letters in search not working that's the problem

Comment: you can accept it as an ans if it works for you so that other may find it helpful

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115096/discussion-between-pramod-and-akshay-kamble).

Answer (score 0):

Ok try it like this

create a file `search_request.xml` in vendor/module/etc directory

now just copy the entire node

```
<request query="quick_search_container" index="catalogsearch_fulltext">
```

from here
**vendor/Magento/CatalogSearch/etc/search_request.xml**

now look for this line

```
<queryReference clause="should" ref="search" />
```

and change it like this

```
<queryReference clause="must" ref="search" />
```

now just add dependency in your etc/module.xml

```
<sequence>        
      <module name="Magento_CatalogSearch"/>
 </sequence>
```

now just remove the module from setup_module table and run `setup:upgrade` or simply just upgrade your module version and run `setup:upgrade`